# Irreducibility of the polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

Prove or disprove.

> Let $f_n(x)=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots +x+1$. Then $f_p(x^{p^{e-1}})$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$ for all prime $p$.

I know if $p$ is a prime $f_p(x)$ is $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial and is irreducible.

Comment: $f_p(x^{p^{e-1}})$ is the $p^e$th cyclotomic polynomial and hence irreducible.

Comment: How to prove that fact

Comment: The most general case is covered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/532960/11619). In this special case [this approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1743605/11619) should work even though it is nominally only about $e=2$.

Comment: To become $p^e$-th cyclotomic polynomial, degrees are not matching.$\phi(p^e)\ne p^{e-1}$.

Comment: I got the method of answer from the quoted question and answer.

Comment: But is this polynomial realy cyclotomic polynomial?